# How to match value between columns in dataframe with empty column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to map the value between the columns in a dataframe. Type of values in my dataframe are list. This is specifically the example of my dataframe :

```
    date      tablenameFrom  tablenameJoin                   attribute
 1 01-03-2019 [item]         []                              [itemID, itemName]
 2 02-03-2019 [order as o]   [customer as c, payment as p]   [o.oderID, p.paymentID,c.firstName]
 3 03-03-2019 [customer c]   [order o]                      [c.customerID, o.orderID]
```

This is what i've tried: [How to match the value of the column between columns in a dataframe, if there is an empty column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822134/10185847). But the solution, can't handle the first row of my dataframe that row have more than one attributes name.

this is what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x 
    in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')

df['tablename']=df['tablenameFrom']+df['tablenameJoin']
yourdf=unnesting(df[['date','tablename','attribute']], ['tablename','attribute'])
yourdf['tablename']=yourdf['tablename'].str.split().str[0]# fix the output
yourdf['attribute']=yourdf['attribute'].str.split(r'[''|.]').str[-1]
yourdf
```

I got error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 561 elements, new values have 412 elements`

I need to map attributes to the tablename. my expected result:

```
   date         tablename   attributename
 1 01-03-2019   item        itemID
 2 01-03-2019   item        itemName
 3 02-03-2019   order       orderID
 4 30-03-2019   customer    firstName
 5 30-03-2019   payment     paymentID
 6 31-03-2019   customer    customerID
 7 31-03-2019   order       orderID
```

I was wondering if someone might be able to give me some solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: what is this: `[order as o]`?  It isn't valid Python.  I can imagine it being a list of one string, or a list with 3 strings, but it doesn't have the right quotes for either.

Comment: [order as o] is an alias for table order. it means "o" stands for "order" table. [order as o] is a list of one string.

Comment: and [customer as c, payment as p] is a list of two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip_longest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30275155) with `None`s for missing values, last repalce them by `ffill` and `bfill` per groups:

```
d = {'date': ['29-03-2019', '30-03-2019', '31-03-2019'],
     'tablenameFrom': [['customer'], ['order as o'], ['customer']], 
     'tablenameJoin': [[], ['customer as c', 'payment as p'], ['order']], 
     'attribute': [['customerID', 'another'], ['o.oderID', 'p.paymentID', 'c.firstName'],
                   ['customerID', 'orderID']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1,2,3])
print (df)
         date tablenameFrom                  tablenameJoin  \
1  29-03-2019    [customer]                             []   
2  30-03-2019  [order as o]  [customer as c, payment as p]   
3  31-03-2019    [customer]                        [order]   

                              attribute  
1                 [customerID, another]  
2  [o.oderID, p.paymentID, c.firstName]  
3                 [customerID, orderID]
```

---

```
from  itertools import zip_longest

x = df['attribute']
y = df['tablenameFrom'] + df['tablenameJoin']
a = [(m, l, k) for m, (i, j) 
               in enumerate(zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=[None])) 
               for k, l 
               in zip_longest(i, j, fillvalue=None)]
#print (a)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['date','tablename','attributename'])
df1['date'] = df['date'].values[df1['date'].values]
df1['tablename'] = df1.groupby('date')['tablename'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

for correct match values is possible use `map`:

```
df2 = df1['tablename'].str.split(' as ', expand=True)
s = df2.dropna().drop_duplicates(1).set_index(1)[0]
print (s)
1
o       order
c    customer
p     payment
Name: 0, dtype: object

df1['attributename'] = df2[1].map(s).fillna(df1['attributename'])
df1['tablename'] = df2[0]
print (df1)
         date tablename attributename
0  29-03-2019  customer    customerID
1  29-03-2019  customer       another
2  30-03-2019     order         order
3  30-03-2019  customer      customer
4  30-03-2019   payment       payment
5  31-03-2019  customer    customerID
6  31-03-2019     order       orderID
```

Comment: forgive me for asking this, but I really don't know how to match the name of the table with its attribute. In your output, the `p.payment` matched with `customer`.

Comment: @wdwilhelmina - hmm, I think here is problem with data, seems some rows are different like in question. Maybe the best is test, whcih rows failed and then is possible find solution.

Comment: i've try your solution in my dataframe and your dataframe. the row which failed are `30-03-2019  p.paymentID      customer` and 
`30-03-2019  c.firstName       payment`

Comment: is possible get problematic row and convert to dict? Like `print (df.loc[125].to_dict())` e.g. if `125` is index of this row.

Comment: yes, it is. if we use your `(df.loc[2].to_dict())`, then i got `{'date': '30-03-2019',
 'tablenameFrom': ['order as o'],
 'tablenameJoin': ['customer as c', 'payment as p'],
 'attribute': ['o.oderID', 'p.paymentID', 'c.firstName']}` and then match the table name to attribute

Comment: @jezrael I still don't understand how to match the tablename and attributename, Would you mind to explain more or if it possible to you to update your solution?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'date': ['29-03-2019', '30-03-2019', '31-03-2019'],
     'tablenameFrom': [['item'], ['order as o'], ['customer']], 
     'tablenameJoin': [[], ['customer as c', 'payment as p'], ['order']], 
     'attribute': [['customerID', 'another'], ['o.oderID', 'p.paymentID', 'c.firstName'],
                   ['customerID', 'orderID']]}

d = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1,2,3])

>>> d
date    tablenameFrom   tablenameJoin   attribute
1   29-03-2019  [item]  []  [customerID, another]
2   30-03-2019  [order as o]    [customer as c, payment as p]   [o.oderID, p.paymentID, c.firstName]
3   31-03-2019  [customer]  [order] [customerID, orderID]

df_list = []
cols = d.columns
for col in d.columns:
    df_ = d[col].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().set_index('level_0')
    df_ = df_.drop(columns='level_1')
    df_list.append(df_)

nw_df = df_list[0]
for df_ in df_list[1:]:
    nw_df = pd.merge(nw_df,df_,on='level_0',how='outer')

nw_df.columns = cols

>>> nw_df
```

[image]